# Copiar enlace a portapapeles c# y asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

He estado viendo distintas formas de copiar un enlace al portapapeles para luego poder pegarlo, pero no encuentro la forma de que me funcione. Tengo lo siguiente que es donde cojo el enlace:

```
        HyperLink enlace = new HyperLink();
        enlace.Target = "_blank";
        enlace.CssClass = "HyperVisitados";
        enlace.NavigateUrl = lista[i].Documento;
```

Y luego tengo esto que es donde creo el botón que haga la funcionalidad de copiar el enlace al portapapeles:

```
         ImageButton boton = new ImageButton();
        boton.ImageUrl = "~/Administracion/imagenes/editar.png";
        boton.ID = "CopiarPortapapeles" + i.ToString();
        boton.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-top:5px");
        boton.OnClientClick = "javascript:alert('"+lista[i].Documento+"')";
```

Tengo un alert para ver que me muestra el enlace correcto que de hecho me lo muestra. He estado probando con el ClipBoard.setText, pero nosé si por cosas del VS o como, no logro hacerlo funcionar. Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: captura del error de la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: veo que usas un `ImageButton` este no realiza un submit del form refrescando la pagina ? de donde sale la variable `lista` ?

Comment: Sí, hace un submit pero no me importa. La variable lista cogela clase correspondiente donde recorre cada fila del for para mostrar el documento correcto. No sé si me explico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esque lo estas haciendo del lado del servidor, la unica forma de que el usuario lo tenga en su equipo es haciendolo mediante javasacript, te dejo el codigo:

Primero tienes que crear una funcion en javascript que copie el texto.
Luego asignarlo mediante ASP.
nada mas:

```js
var copyToClipboard = function(secretInfo) {
    var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var $tempInput = document.createElement('INPUT');
    $body.appendChild($tempInput);
    $tempInput.setAttribute('value', secretInfo)
    $tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $body.removeChild($tempInput);
}
```

```
HyperLink enlace = new HyperLink();
enlace.Target = "_blank";
enlace.CssClass = "HyperVisitados";
enlace.NavigateUrl = lista[i].Documento;

ImageButton boton = new ImageButton();
boton.ImageUrl = "~/Administracion/imagenes/editar.png";
boton.ID = "CopiarPortapapeles" + i.ToString();
boton.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-top:5px");
boton.OnClientClick = "javascript:copyToClipboard('"+lista[i].Documento+"')";
```

Modifique la parte del código para que funcione.

Comment: Resulta que de javascript domino lo mínimo pero he hecho lo que me has comentado y me da error en la función de javascript y no llega a copiarse nada. A que puede deberse?

Comment: puedes campurar el error y subirlo o masomenos que te muestra en la consola?

Comment: Claro. Te muestro el error en mi comentario de arriba. Muchas gracias.